# RegEx parsing for config files

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

in my c# application I want to parse configuration files that are all looking like the following lines:

```
Attribute1 = Value1
Attribute2 = Value2
Attribute3 = Value3
```

Thats why I take the files line by line and try to match them with a RegEx. Currently I got the following regex:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(s, @"^" + attribute + @"[\s]* [=] [\s]* (^.*)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Actually, this is not working. I think the part after the `=` is the problem, since without that one it is working fine. Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this string? Thanks already in advance!

Comment: `^` can be a starting anchor *or* mean **not**. In this case you are saying "not anything for 0 or more characters", which will never capture anything.

Comment: You do not need to wrap all your characters in square brackets `[]`. This is only needed if several different values can take the place. In your case, `@"\s*=\s*"` is equivalent of `@"[\s]*[=][\s]*"`

Comment: You should remove spaces `" "` from your regex as they are interpreted as literal spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the character groups, etc. For me as a newbie in regex parsing these are really useful hints!

Comment: That's why I left the comments ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the starting anchor `^` present inside the capturing group where `^` asserts that we are at the start of a line. And also you don't need to include `=` inside a character class just `=` would be fine. `\s*` matches zero or more spaces so you don't need to include a space explicitly after `\s*`.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(s, @"^" + attribute + @"\s*=\s*(.*)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that the `file` holds the string. Then you can simply do this without any need for a regex.

```
var keyValPair = file.Split('\n').ToDictionary(k => k.Split('=')[0].Trim(),
                                               v => v.Split('=')[1].Trim());
```

Now you've a key-value `Dictionary`, where attribute's name will be the key and attribute's value will be the value.

Comment: This is a actually a good answer, showing an alternative approach to more quickly (and most likely also more efficiently) get the desired output.